# Правильно создание объекта и загрузка данных

Tags: java, netty

У меня есть сервер, прокси и синхронизирующий сервер.

Итак.

Сервер - это место где игроки играют.
Прокси - является связующим звеном между серверами(позволяет переходить игроку с одного сервера на другой).
Синхронизирующий сервер - Сервер и прокси подключается к нему(Здесь используется netty), он выполняет работу что-то вроде хранилища. Хранит о себе информацию о сервера(Пример: Статус на сервер(ожидание, идет игра, перезагрузка)).

Подробно мелочи системы писать не буду.

Игрок подключается к прокси. Прокси посылает пакет синхронизирующему ядру. О том на какой сервер нужно отправить игрока.

У меня возникает вопрос. Я хочу хранить всю информацию об игроке на синхронизирующем сервере. Но информации настолько много что я незнаю как ее максимально быстро загружать из базы данных и отправлять на сервера к которым подключается игрок. Т.к для работы с игроком серверу нужна эта информация(да конечно я понимаю что мог с самого сервера делать запрос в базу данных но тут проблема между синхронизацией на всех серверах информации игрока которая берет из базы данных). Я решил отправлять ее от синхронизирующего сервера к серверу к которому подключается игрок, а в случае изменения данных игрока от другого сервера, отправлять на сервер на котором игрок пакет с уже обновленной информации (так сказать синхронизация).

Но вот я столкнулся с первой проблему. Когда игрок подключается к прокси. Я отправляю пакет от прокси к синхронизирующему серверу. Синхронизирующий сервер создает объект класса игрока и должен загрузить данные игрока и передать их прокси.

Встали некоторые вопросы:

1.Как максимально быстро взять данные из базы?
2.Как правильно рассортировать данные игрока?(Не пихать все данные в один класс как сделал это я)

Пока что я сделал вот такую заготовку. Прошу вас указать на мои ошибки. И как сделать это наиболее лучшим образом?

```
public class Player {
private String name;//Имя игрока
private String ip;//Ип игрока
private Server server;//Сервер на котором находится игрока.
private Proxy proxy;//Прокси к которой подключен игрок.
private int bans;//Банов получено
private int mutes;//Мутов получено
private int warns;//Жалоб получено
private int banned_players;//Забанено им
private int muted_players;//Замучено им
private int warned_players;//Отправленно жалоб на него
private long banStart;//Когда забанили.
private long banEnd;//Когда конец бана.
private long muteStart;//когда замутили.
private long muteEnd;//Когда конец мута
private int kicks;//Сколько раз его кикали.
private int kicked_players;//Сколько раз он кикнул.
private int karma;//Карма игрока
private int level;//Уровень игрока
private int xp;//Опыт игрока
private int coins;//Монетки игрока
private long last_join_date;//Последний раз был в сети.
private long timePlayed;//Время которое он находится на проекте.
private long registered_date;//Дата когда аккаунт был создан.
private String password;//Пароль игрока.
private String code;//Код игрока.
private String mute_cause;//Причина мута.
private String ban_cause;//Причина бана.
private String muteEnforcer;//Имя того кто замутил.
private String banEnforcer;//Имя того кто забанил

public Player(String name, String ip) {
    this.name = name;
    this.ip = ip;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setIp(String ip) {
    this.ip = ip;
}

public void setProxy(Proxy proxy) {
    this.proxy = proxy;
}

public void setServer(Server server) {
    this.server = server;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getIp() {
    return ip;
}

public Proxy getProxy() {
    return proxy;
}

public Server getServer() {
    return server;
}

public boolean isMuted() {
    return (muteEnd > System.currentTimeMillis());
}

public boolean isBanned() {
    return (banEnd > System.currentTimeMillis());
}

public void mute(String muteEnforcer , int time, String time_format, String cause) {
}
```

}

Возник вопрос. Если я буду использовать netty не только для синхронизаций серверов с прокси. То при 1000 онлайн пользователях и при частых перемещениях от одного сервера к другому. Не могут ли у меня возникнуть проблемы со скоростью обработки и передачи информации  от синхронизирующего сервера?

Answer (score 0):

Небольшое замечание относительно кода класса, старайтесь соблюдать консистентность в рамках одной сущности - определитесь, использовать ли snake_case или camelCase. В Java принят camelCase.

Поля класса я бы предложил поделить по общей смысловой нагрузке на более мелкие классы. Например (вложенность/видимость не учитывал, здесь не имеет значения, цель показать принцип выделения подсущностей):

```
public class Player {

    private String name;// Имя игрока
    private RemoteInfo remoteInfo;
    private Stats userStats;
    private Account userDetails;
    private BanInfo banInfo;
    private MuteInfo muteInfo;

    // следующие поля также можно вынести в отдельные небольшие классы
    private int warns;// Жалоб получено
    private int warned_players;// Отправленно жалоб на него
    private int kicks;// Сколько раз его кикали.
    private int kicked_players;// Сколько раз он кикнул.

    /**
     * Инфа отосительно банов
     */
    private class BanInfo {
        private String ban_cause;// Причина бана.
        private String banEnforcer;// Имя того кто забанил => bannedBy
        private long banStart;// Когда забанили.
        private long banEnd;// Когда конец бана.
        private int bans;// Банов получено => bansReceived
        private int banned_players;// Забанено им => bansReceived
    }

    /**
     * Инфа отосительно мьютов
     */
    private class MuteInfo {
        private int mutes;// Мутов получено
        private long muteStart;// когда замутили.
        private long muteEnd;// Когда конец мута
        private int muted_players;// Замучено им
        private String mute_cause;// Причина мута.
        private String muteEnforcer;// Имя того кто замутил.
    }

    /**
     * Идентифицирующая инфа, откуда игрок пришел
     */
    private class RemoteInfo {
        private String ip;// Ип игрока
        private Server server;// Сервер на котором находится игрока.
        private Proxy proxy;// Прокси к которой подключен игрок.
    }

    /**
     * Статистика игрока
     */
    private class Stats {
        private int karma;// Карма игрока
        private int level;// Уровень игрока
        private int xp;// Опыт игрока
        private int coins;// Монетки игрока
    }

    /**
     * Центральная инфа аккаунта
     */
    private class Account {
        private long last_join_date;// Последний раз был в сети.
        private long timePlayed;// Время которое он находится на проекте.
        private long registered_date;// Дата когда аккаунт был создан.
        private String password;// Пароль игрока.
        private String code;// Код игрока.
    }
}
```